# Show the variation label (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

I'm using this slightly modified script (inside a loop) which helps me generate two links which I use to add products to the cart:

```
<?php 
// Get the ID of the product
$id = $_POST["post_var"];

// Get variations
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
    'numberposts' => 2,
    'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
    'order'       => 'asc',
    'post_parent' => $product->id
);

$variations = get_posts( $args );
$loop = 0;

if ( $variations ) {
    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
        $formats[$loop]["id"]      = absint( $variation->ID );
        $formats[$loop]["data"]      = get_post_meta( $variation->ID );
        $variation_label            = "?????????";
        $loop++;
    }

    foreach ( $formats as $type )

    $response .= '<a href="' . home_url() . '/checkout?add-to-cart=' . $product_id . '&variation_id=' . $type["id"] . '&quantity=1&attribute_pa_format=' . $variation_label . '">' . $variation_label . '</a>';
} ?>

<?php echo $response; ?>
```

The only thing I can't figure out is how to get the variation labels.

Every product has variation called "Format' with the options "Electronic" and "Physical" and I need those to be output into the link. So the $response would look something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/checkout?add-to-cart=93&variation_id=94&quantity=1&attribute_pa_format=Electronic">Electronic</a
<a href="http://example.com/checkout?add-to-cart=93&variation_id=95&quantity=1&attribute_pa_format=Physical">Physical</a>
```

You can see I've added a variable called $variation_label as a placeholder.

Stumped.

Comment: have you checked/tried `var_dump($variation);`?

Comment: @Reigel it returns this: http://pastebin.com/zmuN2wNt

Comment: I think you're better of using `$product->get_available_variations();` try that... use `var_dump` to check the value..

Comment: @Reigel use $product->get_available_variations() instead of what?

Comment: to rewrite your code.. use `var_dump`.. I think all of what you needed is there instead of using `get_post`